# QGraphicsLinearLayout not aligning widgets as expected

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qt5

I have got a QGraphicsScene that I have added a QGraphicsWidget.

I initially setup the widget this way

```
 AGraphicsWidget::AGraphicsWidget( QGraphicsItem* parent, QGraphicsScene* scene )
        : QGraphicsWidget( parent )
        , m_mainLayout( new QGraphicsLinearLayout( Qt::Vertical ) )
        , m_titleLabel( new QLabel( "Title" ) )
        , m_executionPin( new NodeExecutionPin() )

    {
        setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding );
        setGraphicsItem( this );
        setFlag( ItemIsMovable, true );

        m_mainLayout->setInstantInvalidatePropagation( true );

        auto* labelProxy = scene->addWidget( m_titleLabel );
        auto* secondLabel = scene->addWidget( new QLabel( "Subtitle" ) );
        auto* button = scene->addWidget( new QPushButton( "Another" ) );

        m_mainLayout->addItem( labelProxy );
        m_mainLayout->addItem( secondLabel );
        m_mainLayout->addItem( button );
        setLayout( m_mainLayout );
    }
```

This setup does not do what I expect which would be a vertically aligned set of widgets instead I get this

[image]

However when I add a text edit as the last element like this

```
AGraphicsWidget::AGraphicsWidget( QGraphicsItem* parent, QGraphicsScene* scene )
        : QGraphicsWidget( parent )
        , m_mainLayout( new QGraphicsLinearLayout( Qt::Vertical ) )
        , m_titleLabel( new QLabel( "Title" ) )
        , m_executionPin( new NodeExecutionPin() )

    {
        setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding );
        setGraphicsItem( this );
        setFlag( ItemIsMovable, true );

        m_mainLayout->setInstantInvalidatePropagation( true );

        auto* labelProxy = scene->addWidget( m_titleLabel );
        auto* secondLabel = scene->addWidget( new QLabel( "Subtitle" ) );
        auto* button = scene->addWidget( new QPushButton( "Another" ) );
        auto* edit = scene->addWidget( new QTextEdit() );

        m_mainLayout->addItem( labelProxy );
        m_mainLayout->addItem( secondLabel );
        m_mainLayout->addItem( button );
        m_mainLayout->addItem( edit );
        setLayout( m_mainLayout );

    }
```

[image]

It works as expected, I get the nice vertical layout, I get the same non alignment as above if I try and nest any QGraphicsLinearLayouts any further where they will overlap each other, what is happening here?

Thanks in advance.